# Center of the map let the user panning just few km or miles

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've a map that is centered with the current location of the user's browser (if the user allowed sharing his position).

I'm going to present markers "around" and I'm thinking how can I limit the panning to 2 km on the four sides (2 km is just an example the idea is to not let the users going too far from the center).

I've already set a zoom limit which help a little but it doesn't solve the situation at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by measuring the distance between the user and the marker locations, and only plot markers within a certain radius (giving a circular area of markers).

Alternatively, you could take the bounds of the map and add a buffer to the coordinates, and then plot markers that lie within the polygon formed by the rectangle using containsLocation() from the Google Maps geometry library (giving a rectangular area of markers. You could also then test if the buffer is panned past and create a new buffer zone, so you are only updating the markers on the map if the user starts panning too far away.

Comment: It's more about how can I set the 2km limit on the four sides. Adding the buffer it's a bit complicated.

Comment: I managed to get the new Bounds set at 2 km from the bounds of the map with the user position in its center. The problem is that I cannot stop the panning at the new bounds+2km. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I would be very surprised if you could stop the user panning past that buffer. You could set the map option 'draggable' to false when the buffer is reached, but then the user couldn't pan back. The only other option that comes to mind would be to listen for dragend, and if they dragged too far (say something like the new center is not contained within a rectangle 2km around the user's location, thus simulating your 2km example buffer) you could reset the center to the nearest edge of that rectangle. They would be able to drag past the buffer but would bounce back to it.

Comment: BTW, I would make it clear to the user that you are preventing them panning further, as they may get pretty annoyed thinking the site wasn't working properly.

Comment: The best option would be crop the map and use just the few square kms around the place where the user is located. My big concern is that each time the user pan there is an ajax request through a php file that check in the db if there are markers in that area, the number of requests can become high if there are lots of trafic.